# javascript:ie8 windows object use onpropertychange to crash

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my html:

```
<p >
  <div id="getArea">
 <textarea class="messageConTextarea" onpropertychange="getLength()"></textarea>
    </div>
  </p>
```

my css:

```
 #getArea .errSytle{
              width: 724px;
              height: 58px;
              border: 1px solid red;
              margin: 10px 0;
              padding: 10px;
          }

#getArea .messageConTextarea{
         width: 724px;
         height: 58px;
         border: 1px solid #abadb3;
         margin: 10px 0;
         padding: 10px;
    }
```

my javascript:

```
function getLength(){
           var modelTitle = $('.messagesCon').find('textarea');   
           modelTitle .css('border','1px solid #abadb3');  
          }
```

chrome,firefox no any problem ,but ie8 have problem,i think that the ie has crashed,it got endless loop. why ie not run as well?please help me. thans!

Comment: this code go to modelTitle .css('border','1px solid #abadb3');   then began getting crash.

Comment: FF and Chrome don't support `onpropertychange`, hence nothing happens. In IE you really get an infinite loop, since you're changing properties of the event target element, and [`onpropertychange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) fires again and again ...

Comment: sorry,i say something is false just moment ago. the ie8 say :loss of object when i use "onpropertychange(this)",  oh, i know you say.your mean is the onpropertychange may fire the ie again and again when i am getting change the textare style?

Comment: Yes, if `modelTitle` is the same `textarea` which has fired `onpropertychange` event. Notice, that `onpropertychange` is _not working_ in any other browser but IE. When working, `onpropertychange` fires even when you move the cursor on the `textarea`. I'd use some more suitable event for what ever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: oh,i know i know.thanks for you help . i want to click button or do something else that give you a sign of good answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onpropertychange` works in IE only, that's why other browsers are not causing troubles.

In IE you create an infinite loop by changing some properties of the same element which had fired the [`propertychange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event.

You can fix the problem by using for example combination of `onkeyup`, `onpaste` and `oncut` to detect changes in the text in `textarea`.

Comment: thanks for your advice,this answer what i want to get.

Comment: In jQuery there's also `input` event, but I'm not sure, if it works in IE8 (it doesn't support native `oninput`). Referring to your previous comment, now there's a button to click ; ).

Comment: If @Teemu answer was the correct one then select the answer as the correct answer.

Comment: hi,i see you comment just now,i have clicked the button for your help.:-)